# Syncing text files from iPhone to windows folder

Tags: sync, iphone, text-editors

I'm looking for a Text editor on the iPhone that can edit multiple files and two-way sync them with a directory on my windows machine whenever I connect the phone.

On my desktop, I use [wikidPad](http://wikidpad.sourceforge.net/) as my editor and keep a zillion files on every conceivable thing (recipes, to do lists, travel itineraries, etc.). I'd love to be able to sync those over to my iPhone, edit them, and sync the changes back and forth.

I know I can use google docs for something like this; I like local text files (for [several reasons](http://lifehacker.com/166299/geek-to-live--list-your-life-in-txt)). I know [Evernote](http://www.evernote.com/about/download/iphone/) can sync notes between iPhone and desktop, but I want to use wikidPad and have all my notes in plain text documents (unless Evernote can a) look like a plain old fixed-width text editor, and b) store its notes as plain text files, in which case I might consider switching).

Any ideas?

Comment: Is there a free alternative to Evernote?

Answer (score 1):

Evernote can be set up to watch folders on your desktop and automatically sync the files within to the "cloud". So you should be able to continue using wikidPad as your desktop editor, and use Evernote as your synchroniser and iPhone editor.